# Trying to make a rect appear on screen without using the "blit" function

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a certain oject, in this case a platform appear on screen as a floating rect without havving to use blit. I have created a class for the platform but it just doesn't appear on screen. I have seen online other people's code working this way and i cannot understand what i am doing wrong. The background works without havin to blit it but the platform doesnt

I have tried seacrhing online for a solution even followed the exact steps of a tutorial but it just doesn't work.

MAIN FILE

```py
import pygame, sys, time
from settings import *
from sprites import BG
from sprites import Platform

pygame.init()


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # setup
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))  # , pygame.FULLSCREEN
        pygame.display.set_caption("Jumpy")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # groups
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # sprite setup
        Platform(self.all_sprites)
        BG(self.all_sprites)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            # game logic
            self.all_sprites.update()
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.display)
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.run()
```

SPRITES

```
import pygame
from settings import *


class BG(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bg_img.png").convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("platform1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midleft=(HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH / 2))
```

Comment: Just swap `BG(self.all_sprites)` and `Platform(self.all_sprites)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to give you an example of what I did. So first of all, I had the line

```py
BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)
```

this is of course a variable for the thing that I want to draw on the screen
then after that I did the line

```py
pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
```

this line of course puts a border in the middle of my screen without needing the blit function. WIN is basically the screen, where i set the size of my screen. black is a variable that is already assigned a colour (0, 0, 0) and border is of course the border. I think you could try and use this code but replace the variable BORDER with whatever you are trying to draw without using the blit function.

Comment: That could work, however i am trying to use the class Platform() in order to make the object appear on screen. I have tried it before so i know it works but in this scenario it just doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that background is drawn before the platform. Use [`pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates) instead of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and add the background before the platform (RenderUpdates draws Sprites in order of addition):

```py
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # setup
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))  # , pygame.FULLSCREEN
        pygame.display.set_caption("Jumpy")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # groups
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()    # <---
        # sprite setup
        BG(self.all_sprites)                                 # <---
        Platform(self.all_sprites)                           # <---

    # [...]
```